# rust borrowed value issue value borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, scope, lifetime, borrow-checker, drop

can't solve this

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::path::Path;
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::collections::HashMap;
extern crate tokenize;
use tokenize::tokenize::words;
extern crate rfts;
use rfts::rfts::{indexing, ftsearch, update};

fn main() {
    let mut upd: HashMap<&str, Vec<(u32, u32)>> = HashMap::new();
    let paths = std::fs::read_dir("./my_folder").unwrap();
    let mut vf = vec![];
    let folder = "./my_folder/".to_string();
    for path in paths {
        vf.push(path.expect("REASON").file_name());
    }
    for i in 0..vf.len() {
        let mut contents = String::new();
        let mut tok = String::new();
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        let file = File::open(folder.clone() + &vf[i].clone().into_string().unwrap());
        file.expect("REASON").read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
        tok = words(contents);
        v = tok.split(" ").collect();
        let ind = indexing(v, i.try_into().unwrap());
        update(ind, &mut upd);
    }
    println!("{:?}", upd);
}
```

the error

```
error[E0597]: tok does not live long enough
--> src/main.rs:26:13
21 |         let mut tok = String::new();
             ------- binding tok declared here...
26 |         v = tok.split(" ").collect();
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough...
29 |     }
         - tok dropped here while still borrowed
30 |     println!("{:?}", upd);
                          --- borrow later used here
```

can explain it? its work without iteration with on item, but in for i dont get

Comment: Hello Bulat, I highly recommend you put your compiler error output in a code block (similar to what you did for the rust code), currently it is very difficult to read.

Comment: I believe this may be because `.split(' ').collect()` will result in a vector with type `Vec<&str>` and what you want is `Vec<String>` to get rid of that error, so you might have to `map` over the vector and create owned strings from the reference.

Comment: Instead of declaring `mut v` and then later stomping that value, just `let v = tok.split(...)`. You could use `to_owned()` here on those `&str` values if you need to persist them outside of that loop.

Comment: let v = tok.split(" ").map(String::from).collect::<Vec<String>>(); thank you